# useQuery: custom names for `loading`, `error` and `data` props

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to use custom names for `loading`, `error` and `data` props? When I try it, I just get `undefined`:

```
const { queryLoading, queryError, queryData } = useQuery(someQuery);
```

This is not a big deal,just could not find anything in documentation and thought maybe there is some trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
const { data: queryData, error: queryError, loading: queryLoading } = useQuery(someQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quite obvious now when I think of it :)